# Create date column from datetime in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, dataframe

I am new to R and I am an avid SAS programmer and am just having a difficult time wrapping my head around R.

Within a data frame I have a date time column formatted as a `POSIXct` with the following the column appearing as `"2013-01-01 00:53:00"`. I would like to create a date column using a function that extracts the date and a column to extract the hour. In an ideal world I would like to be able to extract the date, year, day, month, time and hour all within the data frame to create these additional columns within the data frame.

Comment: That's not a very nice username; especially when asking R users for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is wise to always to be careful with `as.Date(as.POSIXct(...))`:

E.g., for me in Australia:

```
df <- data.frame(dt=as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 00:53:00"))
df
#                   dt
#1 2013-01-01 00:53:00

as.Date(df$dt)
#[1] "2012-12-31"
```

You'll see that this is problematic as the dates don't match. You'll hit problems if your `POSIXct` object is not in the `UTC` timezone as `as.Date` defaults to `tz="UTC"` for this class. See here for more info: [as.Date(as.POSIXct()) gives the wrong date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098862/as-dateas-posixct-gives-the-wrong-date)
To be safe you probably need to match your timezones:

```
as.Date(df$dt,tz=Sys.timezone()) #assuming you've just created df in the same session:
#[1] "2013-01-01"
```

Or safer option #1:

```
df <- data.frame(dt=as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 00:53:00",tz="UTC"))
as.Date(df$dt)
#[1] "2013-01-01"
```

Or safer option #2:

```
as.Date(df$dt,tz=attr(df$dt,"tzone"))
#[1] "2013-01-01"
```

Or alternatively use `format` to extract parts of the `POSIXct` object:

```
as.Date(format(df$dt,"%Y-%m-%d"))
#[1] "2013-01-01"
as.numeric(format(df$dt,"%Y"))
#[1] 2013
as.numeric(format(df$dt,"%m"))
#[1] 1
as.numeric(format(df$dt,"%d"))
#[1] 1
```

Comment: I guess using `Sys.timezone()` would make the results rather fragile, but I like the second option.

Comment: @Frank - that assumes that the `as.POSIXct()` is run in the same timezone, which it probably would be if the object just got created. But good point.

Comment: @Frank - i've added some alternatives that might be safer.

Comment: @thelatemail I've updated my answer too to fix both issues, but I'll +1 yours (once my daily limit resets haha) for your multiple solutions.

Comment: @Synergist - thanks. Timezone/date issues are quite tricky in R and falling afoul of them is easy. I'm constantly surprised how often they are relevant.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `lubridate` package. For example, if `df` is a `data.frame` with a column `dt` of type `POSIXct`, then you could:

```
df$date = as.Date(as.POSIXct(df$dt, tz="UTC"))
df$year = year(df$dt)
df$month = month(df$dt)
df$day = day(df$dt)
# and so on...
```

If your can store your data in a `data.table`, then this is even easier:

```
df[, `:=`(date = as.Date(as.POSIXct(dt, tz="UTC")), year = year(dt), ...)]
```

Comment: The last line will not work as written. All of the `:=` must appear in the second argument of `df[,]`, maybe something like `df[,c("date","year","month","day"):=lapply(c(as.Date,year,month,day),function(f)f(dt))]` I'm not sure that that will work exactly as written either, though.

Comment: @Frank I think just ```dt[, `:=`(date = as.Date(dt), year = year(dt), ...)]```. Other than that, you are right, the `data.table` solution in the answer won't work.

Comment: Doing `as.Date(df$dt)` can also give unpredictable results dependent on your timezone - it does for me with the example data - see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098862/as-dateas-posixct-gives-the-wrong-date

Comment: @DavidArenburg - you can also do `c("date","year"):=list(datecode,yearcode)` for `j` as well

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks for that info! I didn't catch onto the troubles as.Date can cause. I've fixed my solution now.