# Why does as.Date() return wrong Date when converting from POSIXct?

Tags: r, date, posixct

I just tried the following:

```
> as.POSIXct('2019-03-11 23:59:59')
[1] "2019-03-11 23:59:59 EDT"
> as.Date(as.POSIXct('2019-03-11 23:59:59'))
[1] "2019-03-12"
```

Why is it '2019-03-12'?

Comment: Related discussions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653521/create-date-column-from-datetime-in-r/30655601 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098862/as-dateas-posixct-gives-the-wrong-date/17099360

Comment: It basically boils down to the default for `as.Date` - `as.Date(x, tz = "UTC", ...)` - which is a [reference time centred on London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) - which can be many hours different from your local timezone which R will use by default when you specify a datetime using `as.POSIXct`.

Comment: I didn't think it was an exact duplicate, but since one of the accepted answers on the proposed duplicates was mine, I went ahead and added what I think was a possible correct answer, i.e. to use `as.Date(format( .... , "%Y-%m-%d"))`