# How would you lookup the next-closest value?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, zoo, posixct

I have the following 2 data.frames:

```
data.df <- data.frame(dt = as.POSIXct(c('2020-01-08 11:30:00', 
    '2020-01-10 11:30:00', '2020-01-11 12:30:00')), 
  v1=c(1,2,3))

lookup.df <- data.frame(ldt = as.POSIXct(c('2020-01-08 11:29:00', 
  '2020-01-08 11:30:00', '2020-01-08 11:31:00', '2020-01-10 10:30:00', 
  '2020-01-10 11:31:00', '2020-01-11 11:30:00', '2020-01-12 11:30:00')), 
   lv = 1:7)
```

For each row in data.df I would like to get a row index in lookup.df (to match rows in a merge)  where lookup.df$ldt >= data.df$dt on the same day. If no date meets that requirement then NA. So in this example the ideal output would be:

```
dt                    |   v1   |  ldt                 |  lv
2020-01-08 11:30:00        1      2020-01-08 11:30:00     2
2020-01-10 11:30:00        2      2020-01-10 11:31:00     5
2020-01-11 12:30:00        3       NA                     NA
```

> NOTE: I would prefer a base R implementation or a zoo implementation

Comment: Why the negative votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Base R - sapply** This uses base R.  For each component of `dt` in `data.df` it finds all datetimes greater than it in `lookup.df` on the same date and then returns the index of the first.  Finally it puts together data.df and the rows of those indexes of `lookup.df` .

```
ix <- sapply(data.df$dt, function(dt) with(lookup.df, 
  which(ldt >= dt & as.Date(ldt, tz = "") == as.Date(dt, tz = ""))[1]
))
res <- cbind(data.df, lookup.df[ix, ])
rownames(res) <- NULL
```

giving:

```
> res
                   dt v1                 ldt lv
1 2020-01-08 11:30:00  1 2020-01-08 11:30:00  2
2 2020-01-10 11:30:00  2 2020-01-10 11:31:00  5
3 2020-01-11 12:30:00  3                <NA> NA
```

**2) Base R - merge**  This is an alternate base R approach.  Append a date column to each input data frame and then merge the two by that column.  Remove any row for which the lookup.df date/time is less than the data.df date/time and then take the first row of each set of rows derived from the same original data.df row.  That will get the matches except that it will miss the rows that have no matches at all so perform a second merge to get those back.

```
data.df$date <- as.Date(data.df$dt, tz = "")
lookup.df$date <- as.Date(lookup.df$ldt, tz = "")

m <- merge(data.df, lookup.df, by = "date", all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)
m <- subset(m, dt <= ldt)
m <- m[!duplicated(m[1:3]), ]
merge(data.df[-3], m[-1], by = c("dt", "v1"), all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)
```

giving:

```
                   dt v1                 ldt lv
1 2020-01-08 11:30:00  1 2020-01-08 11:30:00  2
2 2020-01-10 11:30:00  2 2020-01-10 11:31:00  5
3 2020-01-11 12:30:00  3                <NA> NA
```

**3) SQL**  Although the question asked for a base R solution an sql solution has been added in addition here because it provides a particularly straight forward translation of the problem into code as a self join with a complex condition.  It performs a left join on the indicated condition and takes the minimum `ldt` found over all rows derived from the same row in data.df.

```
library(sqldf)

data.df$date <- as.Date(data.df$dt, tz = "")
lookup.df$date <- as.Date(lookup.df$ldt, tz = "")

sqldf("select D.dt, D.v1, min(L.ldt) as ldt, L.lv
  from [data.df] D left join [lookup.df] L
  on D.dt <= L.ldt and D.date == L.date
  group by D.rowid")
```

giving:

```
                   dt v1                 ldt lv
1 2020-01-08 11:30:00  1 2020-01-08 11:30:00  2
2 2020-01-10 11:30:00  2 2020-01-10 11:31:00  5
3 2020-01-11 12:30:00  3                <NA> NA
```

### Note

There was a problem in the question with fancy quotes that R cannot read so we used this as the input:

```
data.df <- data.frame(dt = as.POSIXct(c('2020-01-08 11:30:00', 
    '2020-01-10 11:30:00', '2020-01-11 12:30:00')), 
  v1=c(1,2,3))

lookup.df <- data.frame(ldt = as.POSIXct(c('2020-01-08 11:29:00', 
  '2020-01-08 11:30:00', '2020-01-08 11:31:00', '2020-01-10 10:30:00', 
  '2020-01-10 11:31:00', '2020-01-11 11:30:00', '2020-01-12 11:30:00')), 
   lv = 1:7)
```

Comment: Sorry about the quotes. Wrote this on an IPad. Updated the question.

Comment: as.Date(...) has issues with converting from POSIXct objects since it assumes the date is UTC. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60329452/why-does-as-date-return-wrong-date-when-converting-from-posixct

Comment: Have added `tz = ""`

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, here is a solution which uses `data.table`'s *rolling join*.

If I understand correctly, the OP is looking for matches

1. on the same day and
2. on the first time stamp encountered in `lookup.df` on or after the time stamp
   given in `data.df

The second condition can be achieved by a simple *rolling join*:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(lookup.df)[setDT(data.df), on = .(ldt = dt), .(dt, v1, ldt = x.ldt, lv), roll = -Inf]
```

> ```
>                     dt v1                 ldt lv
> 1: 2020-01-08 11:30:00  1 2020-01-08 11:30:00  2
> 2: 2020-01-10 11:30:00  2 2020-01-10 11:31:00  5
> 3: 2020-01-11 12:30:00  3 2020-01-12 11:30:00  7
> ```

However, it is obvious that the first condition is violated for row 3. In order to fulfill the first condition, we have to match on the same day as well. This requires to add a `day` column of type `Date` to both data frames:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(lookup.df)[, .(ldt, lv, day = as.IDate(ldt))][
  setDT(data.df)[, .(dt, v1, day = as.IDate(dt))], 
  on = .(day, ldt = dt), .(dt, v1, ldt = x.ldt, lv), roll = -Inf]
```

> ```
>                     dt v1                 ldt lv
> 1: 2020-01-08 11:30:00  1 2020-01-08 11:30:00  2
> 2: 2020-01-10 11:30:00  2 2020-01-10 11:31:00  5
> 3: 2020-01-11 12:30:00  3                <NA> NA
> ```

Note that `data.df` and `lookup.df` aren't modified.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your lookup times are ordered, in base R you can do:

```r
lv <- sapply(data.df$dt, function(x){
  which(substr(lookup.df$ldt, 1, 10) == substr(x, 1, 10) & lookup.df$ldt >= x)[1]
})

cbind(data.df, lookup.df[lv,])
#>                     dt v1                 ldt lv
#> 2  2020-01-08 11:30:00  1 2020-01-08 11:30:00  2
#> 5  2020-01-10 11:30:00  2 2020-01-10 11:31:00  5
#> NA 2020-01-11 12:30:00  3                <NA> NA
```

If you don't mind using `lubridate` you can use `date()` instead of `substr()`

Comment: Would have picked this answer but this way is so slow when you have a very large lookup table. Ended up using @Grothendieck’s method as it is quite fast. I do appreciate the answer as it is the most readable!

Answer (score 1):

And for the sake of complete and utter completeness, here's a **dplyr** version with a **fuzzyjoin** flavour:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)

fuzzy_left_join(data.df, lookup.df, by = c("day" = "day", "dt" = "ldt"), 

                match_fun = list(`==`, `<=`)) %>%
    select(-c(day.x, day.y)) %>%
    group_by(v1) %>% slice(1)

  dt                     v1 ldt                    lv
  <dttm>              <dbl> <dttm>              <int>
1 2020-01-08 11:30:00     1 2020-01-08 11:30:00     2
2 2020-01-10 11:30:00     2 2020-01-10 11:31:00     5
3 2020-01-11 12:30:00     3 NA                     NA
```