# Get month, day and hour from string

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have a Data Frame with dates in this format `2014-06-10 06:12:35 BRT` I would compare dates to see if they are part of the same social day (3:00 to 3:00 am on a day to another). But when I try to select only the day

```
format(as.Date(df$x,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"), "%d"),
```

sometimes he adds + 1, for example 
`2014-06-13 22:54:36 BRT` it shows `14`.

And if I try to take the time

```
format(as.Date(df$x,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"), "%H")
```

it appears always `00`.

How should I work with dates in the R?

Comment: Your `format` doesn't match `"2014-06-13 22:54:36 BRT"`. Please fix.

Comment: You've been struck by timezone differences - same issue as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098862/as-dateas-posixct-gives-the-wrong-date/17099360 Make sure that `tz=` matches for `as.Date`

Comment: Try for instance `as.Date(as.POSIXct("2014-06-13 22:54:36", tz="Brazil/East"), tz="Brazil/East")` and compare to `as.Date(as.POSIXct("2014-06-13 22:54:36", tz="Brazil/East"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R, times use `POSIXct` and `POSIXlt` classes and dates use the `Date` class.

Dates are stored as the number of days since January 1st, 1970 and times are stored as the number of seconds since January 1st, 1970.

So, for example:

```
d <- as.Date("1971-01-01")
unclass(d)  # one year after 1970-01-01
# [1] 365

pct <- Sys.time()  # in POSIXct
unclass(pct)  # number of seconds since 1970-01-01
# [1] 1450276559
plt <- as.POSIXlt(pct)
up <- unclass(plt)  # up is now a list containing the components of time
names(up)
# [1] "sec"    "min"    "hour"   "mday"   "mon"    "year"   "wday"   "yday"   "isdst"  "zone"  
# [11] "gmtoff"
up$hour
# [1] 9
```

To perform operations on dates and times:

```
plt - as.POSIXlt(d)
# Time difference of 16420.61 days
```

And to process dates, you can use `strptime()` (borrowing these examples from the manual page):

```
strptime("20/2/06 11:16:16.683", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%OS")
# [1] "2006-02-20 11:16:16 EST"

# And in vectorized form:
dates <- c("1jan1960", "2jan1960", "31mar1960", "30jul1960")
strptime(dates, "%d%b%Y")
# [1] "1960-01-01 EST" "1960-01-02 EST" "1960-03-31 EST" "1960-07-30 EDT"
```

*To process your specific date[s]:*

```
dateString <- "2014-06-10 06:12:35"
d <- strptime(dateString, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

**NOTE:** *I'm not finding the "BRT" timezone in the R list of zones, so my time above is set to the EDT timezone:*

```
"BRT" %in% OlsonNames()
# [1] FALSE
```