# as.Date in R completely changes the years

Tags: r, time-series, xts, as.date

I have a time-series dataset in csv format. The monthly data is from 4/1/1953 to 6/1/2017. I want to convert this into an xts object in R. I used the following codes to import the dataset and then convert into xts. However, after the conversion, my time index starts from 2019-01-01. I have attached a snippet of my xts object here for your convenience. [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URyzb.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/URyzb.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URyzb.png)

```
data<-read.csv("10year_3month_treas_Bond_eq_spread.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
data$DATE=as.Date(data$DATE,"%m/%d/%y")
data<-as.xts(data[,-1], order.by = data[,1])
```

I will be grateful if you could help me fix this.

Comment: Please review [mcve].

Comment: try `%Y` - its case sensitive

Comment: Thanks G. Grothendieck. I am not sure which part needs further clarification. Could you please point me in the right direction? Thanks for your time.

Comment: @RichardTelford Thanks a bunch!!! Just the fix I was looking for. I am new to R and still trying to find my ways around. Please accept my sincere gratitude.

Comment: If anyone wonders why not the year but the day changed (even if format = "%Y-%m-%d" is set), see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17099008/11783513

Answer (score 2):

Joshua Ulrich,

You may have probably fixed the issue already but I am hoping my answer would be helpful for someone else. When specifying the year in R, use "y" for 2-digit year such as 99, 05 whereas "Y" for 4-digit year such as 1999, 2005. The code above may be fixed by replacing date format "%m/%d/%y" with "%m/%d/%Y."

Have a great day!