# How to find the percentage of observations in each day in R?

Tags: r, percentage

I have a dataset with time, where the time intervals are 6 hours apart and I have a column of heaterstatus.
The dataset :

[image]

I would like to know the percentage of zero occurred in each day for heaterstatus. New to R, any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Hi @Notslayer205, please provide your data in a copy-paste able form using `dput()`, [not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/17303805). See [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/17303805) for more details on how to ask an effective R question on Stack Overflow. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative frequencies / proportions with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576515/relative-frequencies-proportions-with-dplyr)

Answer (score 1):

Not tested since you only provided data as an image, but this should do what you want:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(day = as.Date(Time)) %>%
  summarize(pct_0 = mean(HeaterStatus == 0))
```

Comment: Generally I think this is the way to go, but you'd have to be careful with `as.Date(Time)` as it can cause issues with timezone conversions e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098862/as-dateas-posixct-gives-the-wrong-date/17099360