# R Script to Calculate Data Completeness in a Dataset

Tags: r

I am trying to create a script to calculate the data completeness (%) based on hourly data for each day. In this example I am using a full year worth of data, but in some cases I would like to look at partial years as well. I have run into some issues when trying to classify the data according to my thresholds/classes (i.e. 100% coverage, >90%, <90%, and missing), currently not identifying correctly March 11 to 14 as missing, and March 8 and 10 as having less than 100% coverage. The legend also does not seem to work as intended.

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated. Of course if I am going in the wrong direction I am open to hearing suggestions on how to best accomplish this.

Thank you

```
# Load necessary libraries
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Read data from the CSV file, skipping the first 14 rows
file_path <- "C:/R SOFTWARE/Air_Temp.Hourly_Air_Temp_(Degrees_C)@BJ_VOK.20220101.csv"
data <- read.csv(file_path, skip = 14, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Parse the Timestamp column using a custom format
data$Timestamp <- as.POSIXct(data$Timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

# Calculate completeness for each day
data_summary <- data %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(Timestamp)) %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarize(
    total_hours = n(),
    complete_hours = sum(!is.na(Value)),
    completeness = complete_hours / total_hours * 100
  )

# Create a color palette for data completeness levels
color_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "yellow", "green"))(100)

# Create a ggplot heatmap-like plot with correct orientation
heatmap_plot <- ggplot(data_summary, aes(x = month(date), y = day(date))) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = completeness), color = "white") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = color_palette, limits = c(0, 100), breaks = c(90, 100), labels = c(">90%", "100%")) +
  labs(title = "Data Completeness Heatmap",
       x = "Month",
       y = "Day of Month",
       fill = "Completeness (%)") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12, labels = month.abb) +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = seq(1, 31, by = 1))  # Reverse days

# Print the heatmap-like plot
print(heatmap_plot)
```

[Resulting Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Beo4x.png)

[Image - Dataset Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/at7Xx.png)

---

### Data

```
    ISO.8601.UTC Timestamp..UTC.09.00.   Value Approval.Level Grade Qualifiers           Timestamp
1   2022-01-01T09:00:00Z   2022-01-01 00:00:00 -10.710        Working     0         NA 2022-01-01 00:00:00
2   2022-01-01T10:00:00Z   2022-01-01 01:00:00 -10.490        Working     0         NA 2022-01-01 01:00:00
3   2022-01-01T11:00:00Z   2022-01-01 02:00:00  -9.790        Working     0         NA 2022-01-01 02:00:00
4   2022-01-01T12:00:00Z   2022-01-01 03:00:00  -7.774        Working     0         NA 2022-01-01 03:00:00
5   2022-01-01T13:00:00Z   2022-01-01 04:00:00  -7.956        Working     0         NA 2022-01-01 04:00:00
6   2022-01-01T14:00:00Z   2022-01-01 05:00:00  -6.222        Working     0         NA 2022-01-01 05:00:00
7   2022-01-01T15:00:00Z   2022-01-01 06:00:00  -7.093        Working     0         NA 2022-01-01 06:00:00
8   2022-01-01T16:00:00Z   2022-01-01 07:00:00  -7.784        Working     0         NA 2022-01-01 07:00:00
9   2022-01-01T17:00:00Z   2022-01-01 08:00:00  -8.510        Working     0         NA 2022-01-01 08:00:00
10  2022-01-01T18:00:00Z   2022-01-01 09:00:00  -8.180        Working     0         NA 2022-01-01 09:00:00
11  2022-01-01T19:00:00Z   2022-01-01 10:00:00  -5.800        Working     0         NA 2022-01-01 10:00:00
12  2022-01-01T20:00:00Z   2022-01-01 11:00:00  -6.227        Working     0         NA 2022-01-01 11:00:00
13  2022-01-01T21:00:00Z   2022-01-01 12:00:00  -6.977        Working     0         NA 2022-01-01 12:00:00
14  2022-01-01T22:00:00Z   2022-01-01 13:00:00  -7.642        Working     0         NA 2022-01-01 13:00:00
```

Comment: It will be much easier to provide concrete suggestions if you can figure out a way to include some sample data (as code, preferably) that we can run your code on. This might be as simple as running `dput(data)` and pasting the output into your question. (Or `dput(head(data))` or something like `dput(data[1:5, c(1,4:6)])` if you only needed to share the first five rows, in columns 1, 4, 5, and 6.)

Comment: "The legend also does not seem to work as intended" does not mean much to us if we don't know what you expected or what it looks like, and don't have any sample data that would allow us to see some output. Can you describe what you expected and what it looks like?

Comment: "currently not identifying correctly March 11 to 14 as missing" do these days appear in the data, with 24 missing values? Are the missing values loading as NAs?

Comment: One potential pitfall to look out for is that `as.Date` will report the local date as if the timestamp were in GMT time. (But this wouldn't explain multiple contiguous days missing.) `lubridate::as_date()` has more sensible (to me) defaults that use the same date as how your timestamp prints out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098862/as-dateas-posixct-gives-the-wrong-date

Comment: Thanks Jon. I have included some of the data. The 2 columns of interest are Timestamp and Value, the rest don't matter.

Comment: As for the other comments, I thought I had included the image, but apparently I can only post a link for now, which I have included. As for the legend "not working" I should have been more clear. It should show 100%, >90% <90% and Missing. Currently not the case.

Comment: WRT to missing days, they are omitted from the dataset i.e. it goes from March 10 then jumps to March 15, there are no N/A or NaN entries in the data table.

Comment: I'll request you please look at my first comment again. Good luck!